# How do I use multiple ATOM Code snippets

Tags: json, atom-editor

I am having trouble using multiple code snippets in Atom. I must be missing some syntax as only the last snippet works. (New HTML page) If I swap the order, this means the BootstrapBlock works, but never both? Any ideas welcome.

```
#BOOTSTRAP BLOCK
".text.html":
  "BootstrapBlock":
    "prefix": "BootstrapBlock"
      "body": '''
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">

            </div><!-- end col -->

        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
'''

#NEW HTML DOCUMENT
".text.html":
  "start":
   "prefix": "start"
    "body": '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale = 1.0">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/img/assets-images/favicon.ico">

        <title></title>

        <!-- FRAMEWORK -->
        <link href="_includes/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="_includes/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

      </head>

      <body>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="_includes/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why only the last snippet works is because you overwrite they key `".text.html"`. Both snippets should be children of the first key, i.e. remove the second `".text.html"` key.